# Объясните причину различного потребления памяти для 2х методов

Tags: c#, память, словари

До:

```
 private static Dictionary<RuleKey, bool> mergeRules(
         Dictionary<RuleKey, bool> topPriorityRules, Dictionary<RuleKey, bool> secondaryRules)
      {
         var resolvedRules = topPriorityRules.Concat(secondaryRules.Where(kvp => !topPriorityRules.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
         return resolvedRules;
      }
```

После:

```
  private static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> merge<TKey, TValue>(
             Dictionary<TKey, TValue> topPriorityRules, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> secondaryRules)
          {
             var resolvedRules = topPriorityRules;

             foreach (var rule in secondaryRules)
                if(!resolvedRules.ContainsKey(rule.Key))
                   resolvedRules.Add(rule.Key, rule.Value);
             return resolvedRules;
          }
```

Есть 2 словаря набора прав, которые нужно объеденить в один. В первом случае при вызове метода 500 раз. Объем занимаемой оперативной памяти занимаемой программой доходит до 1ГБ. Во втором случае, около 300МБ. Почему такие отличия в потреблении памяти? Ведь по сути методы выполняют одно и то же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что ты 500 раз создаешь новый словарь в методе `ToDictionary`:

```
    Dictionary<TKey, TElement> d = new Dictionary<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in source) d.Add(keySelector(element), elementSelector(element));
```

Comment: спасибоза ответ, в моем случае это очень сильно забивало память

Answer (score 0):

Использование Linq в первом случае и отсутствия Linq во втором. В первом случае вся выборка непосредственно выгружена будет в память. а во втором по мере необходимости...

Comment: Использование LINQ тут не особо причём

Comment: @VladD Денис может думал что LinQ тратит больше памяти, возможно это так, но я знаю точно что LinQ тратит больше времени, но катастрофически много, но тратит, но точно не занимает в 5 раз больше памяти ...

Comment: Тратит больше времени? По сравнению с чем?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников например обычный цикл. Напишите обычный цикл и заверните его, например через решарпер в LinQ, и поставьте StopWatch'ей

Comment: @ParanoidPanda возможно имелось ввиду, что нет возможности совместить 2 dictionary c использованием Linq без использования ToDictionary. Чтобы в конечном итоге получился один Dictionary. Так же, при решении данной проблемы, я натыкался на негодование по поводу отсутствие возможности передать в конструктор Dictionary тип IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>